# What is the most efficient way to simulate a countdown in java?

Tags: java, optimization, sleep, countdown

I want to print to the console every second. So far, I've been able to think of two ways to do this.

`long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();`

```
    while(true){
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis()  - start_time) >= 1000) {
            System.out.println("One second passed");
            start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
```

And this

```
   while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("One second passed");
        }
```

Is any method safer or more reliable or more efficient than the other?
or maybe there are use cases for each?
Thanks

Comment: Or look at `ScheduledExecutorService`.   Note that the functionality you seem to be describing is not a stopwatch.  It is more like a chiming clock that chimes every second.

Comment: @StephenC, yeah true.

Comment: Maybe class `java.util.Timer` is appropriate?

Comment: and simpler too @Abra. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as simple as it seems.

The problem with your solutions are that the first is very inefficient, and the second is liable to drift because `sleep(1000)` does not guarantee to sleep for exactly 1 second.  (The javadoc says that `sleep(1000)` sleeps for *at least* one second.)

One possibility is to use `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay` and compute the delay each time by looking at the difference between the millisecond clock and your start time (or end time).  That will keep your messages in sync with real time (more or less).

Or maybe you can simplify that using `scheduleAtFixedRate`, because it looks like `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` will take care of the clock syncing problem.

Another possibility is to look for a 3rd-party library that implements a "cron-like" scheduler in Java.

Comment: I'm taking a look at at the ```ScheduledExecutorService```  from the docs now. For learning sake though, how does the ScheduledExecutorService internally work if not sleep ?

Comment: The `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` uses `Lock.Condition.await` with a nanosecond delay.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You can use `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate`
to create a countdown

Comment: I think you are right.  I just got there myself.  See above.